# Sending email with attachments after crawling a website

Tags: python, email, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy for a school project to find dead links and missing pages. I've written pipelines for writing text files with the relevant scraped information. I'm having trouble with figuring out how to send an email at the end of the spiders run with the files that were made as attachments.

Scrapy has built in email functionality and fires signals when the spider finishes, but getting everything together in a way that is sensible is eluding me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my pipeline for creating the files with scraped data:

```
class saveToFile(object):

def __init__(self):
    # open files
    self.old = open('old_pages.txt', 'wb')
    self.date = open('pages_without_dates.txt', 'wb')
    self.missing = open('missing_pages.txt', 'wb')

    # write table headers
    line = "{0:15} {1:40} {2:} \n\n".format("Domain","Last Updated","URL")
    self.old.write(line)

    line = "{0:15} {1:} \n\n".format("Domain","URL")
    self.date.write(line)

    line = "{0:15} {1:70} {2:} \n\n".format("Domain","Page Containing Broken Link","URL of Broken Link")
    self.missing.write(line)

def process_item(self, item, spider):

    # add items to file as they are scraped
    if item['group'] == "Old Page":
        line = "{0:15} {1:40} {2:} \n".format(item['domain'],item["lastUpdated"],item["url"])
        self.old.write(line)
    elif item['group'] == "No Date On Page":
        line = "{0:15} {1:} \n".format(item['domain'],item["url"])
        self.date.write(line)
    elif item['group'] == "Page Not Found":
        line = "{0:15} {1:70} {2:} \n".format(item['domain'],item["referrer"],item["url"])
        self.missing.write(line)

    return item
```

I would like to create a separate pipeline item for sending the email. What I have so far is the following:

```
class emailResults(object):

def __init__(self):

    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, spider_closed)
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, spider_opened)

    old = open('old_pages.txt', 'wb')
    date = open('pages_without_dates.txt', 'wb')
    missing = open('missing_pages.txt', 'wb')
    oldOutput = open('twenty_oldest_pages.txt', 'wb')

attachments = [
            ("old_pages", "text/plain", old)
            ("date", "text/plain", date)
            ("missing", "text/plain", missing)
            ("oldOutput", "text/plain", oldOutput)
        ]

        self.mailer = MailSender()
def spider_closed(SPIDER_NAME):

    self.mailer.send(to=["example@gmail.com"], attachs=attachments, subject="test email", body="Some body")
```

It seems that in previous versions of Scrapy you could pass self into the spider_closed function, but in the current version (0.21) the spider_closed function is only passed the spider name.

Any help and/or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating mailer sending class as pipeline is not the best idea. Better create it as your own extension. You can read more about extensions here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html.

The most important part is class method from_crawler. It is called for all your crawlers, and in it you can register your callbacks for signals that you want to intercept. 
For example this function from my mailer class looks like this:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    recipients = crawler.settings.getlist('STATUSMAILER_RECIPIENTS')
    if not recipients:
        raise NotConfigured

    mail = MailSender.from_settings(crawler.settings)
    instance = cls(recipients, mail, crawler)

    crawler.signals.connect(instance.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_error, signal=signals.spider_error)
    crawler.signals.connect(instance.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
    crawler.signals.connect(instance.item_dropped, signal=signals.item_dropped)

    return instance
```

For convenient usage remember to set up all necessary data in your settings:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'your.mailer': 80
}

STATUSMAILER_RECIPIENTS = ["who should get mail"]

MAIL_HOST = '***'
MAIL_PORT = ***
MAIL_USER = '***'
MAIL_PASS = '***'
```